Margin-right of a flex div not respected on narrow-width viewports
I have an image and a <p> inside a <div class = "man"> with display: flex. When I try to resize the window with the dev tools, the margin-right of the div colored with orange in the image is not respected, so the image seems stuck to the right side. The image for now has no padding/margin, but there is a margin applied to the div that contains both the <p> and the <img>; why is it not respected?
Screenshot of my issue w/ dev tools open
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    div.man {
      max-width: fit-content;
      margin: 20px;
      display: flex;
    }
    div.man p {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    div.man img {
      max-width: 450px;
      height: auto;
    }
    @media (max-width: 655px) {
      div.man {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px;">
  <div style="width: fit-content;" class="man">
    <img src="man2.jpg">
    <p>Questo concept restaurant desidera donare ai propri membri un viaggio sensoriale e spirituale tramite le linee
  del design, l'attenta scelta dei suoni, l'accurata selezione delle essenze, un'altra riflessione della
  funzionalità e della comodità
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>


you didn't specify any width to the image (only a max-width) so I suppose it's overflowing

thanks but i tried right now with some width values of the img, but i have the same problem so i think solution is different ...

What about img {width: 100%;}?

@ralph.m thanks now it seems to work, can you explain me why this edit and how this works? Why setting 100% width the image doesn't fill all the cointainer div.man instead there is space for both the image and even the ?

This is a box model issue. The margin property does not work as many expect. When you apply a margin to an element the space is applied outside of the box model. This is why your image is shifted slightly past the viewport - the extra margin is pushing it out of the box model.
The width on the flex parent is set to fit-content but it also has a margin of 20px on all sides. This means that the flex parent box model will use the available space, but never more than max-content. In this case the max-content would be the width of the viewport, but since the flex parent has a margin of 20px on all sides the max-content is calculated in an unexpected way which makes it 20px wider than the viewport.
There are a few ways to address this. For the least amount of changes, I would recommend adjusting your CSS to reflect the following:
div.man {
    max-width: fit-content;
    padding: 20px;
    gap: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

Also make sure to close and reopen Chrome developer tools.

Thanks for the help i marked you answers as correct, can you explain me the key difference between margin and padding? I think that margin "pushes" the other elements around it instead padding creates a real "margin" that not even resizing the viewport can brake, so margin means the outside space between an element and the other elements and padding is more like an inside margin, am i right?

@Stefan9669 Here is a link to help give a visual representation of the box model. You can see where the padding and margin values are applied: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp
I suggest doing more research on the box model and doing your own experiments as the box model is the foundation for CSS.

I am assuming that when you say respected, you want the image to fill the entire page, but limit it to a maximum width of 450px. If this is the case, then what I have done is added a width: 100% under div.man img.
Notice that with this, the image margins are still in place, but the width of the image is not distorting the page layout.


div.man {
  max-width: fit-content;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

div.man p {
  margin: 0px;
}

div.man img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
  height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 655px) {
  div.man {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body style="margin: 0px;">
  <div style="width: fit-content;" class="man">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
    <p>
      Questo concept restaurant desidera donare ai propri membri un viaggio sensoriale e spirituale tramite le linee del design, l'attenta scelta dei suoni, l'accurata selezione delle essenze, un'altra riflessione della funzionalità e della comodità
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>




Yes this solves my problem now when i resize the window the margin right is respected so it's what i'm looking for, before marking the answer can you explain me why setting the width to 100% ? And why with width: 100%; the image doesn't fill all its container div.man? There is space for both the  and the , and it's right but i don't understand why with width 100% it doesn't fill all the space inside the container

There are two aspects. First, setting the width to be 100% means that the image will fill the entire width of the containing div, in this case, div class man.
The other aspect is that the width has a maximum width of 450px, meaning that if the width of the containing div is bigger than 450px, the image will not stretch beyond that.

In CSS, a margin is the space around an element's border, while padding is the space between an element's border and the element's content. If you are setting margin for a full width element, you may need to set its width using calc like width:calc(100% - 2x) where x stands for margin.
However, in your case, I believe using padding is a better choice. (Obviously, use it with box-sizing.)


 div.man {
      max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
      margin: 20px;
      display: flex;
    }
    div.man p {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    div.man img {
      max-width: 450px;
      height: auto;
    }
    @media (max-width: 655px) {
      div.man {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    }
    
    body{margin:0}
  <div style="width: fit-content;" class="man">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Fronalpstock_big.jpg/1200px-Fronalpstock_big.jpg">
    <p>Questo concept restaurant desidera donare ai propri membri un viaggio sensoriale e spirituale tramite le linee
  del design, l'attenta scelta dei suoni, l'accurata selezione delle essenze, un'altra riflessione della
  funzionalità e della comodità
    </p>
  </div>




Either set the width on div.man to "auto" or "initial" or just remove the inline rule of "fit-content".


div.man {
      width: auto !important;
      margin: 20px;
      display: flex;
    }
    div.man p {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    div.man img {
      max-width: 450px;
      height: auto;
    }
    @media (max-width: 655px) {
      div.man {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    }
<body style="margin: 0px;">
  <div style="width: fit-content;" class="man">
    <img src="https://place.dog/450/250">
    <p>Questo concept restaurant desidera donare ai propri membri un viaggio sensoriale e spirituale tramite le linee
  del design, l'attenta scelta dei suoni, l'accurata selezione delle essenze, un'altra riflessione della
  funzionalità e della comodità
    </p>
  </div>
</body>




I guess that the issue which you are encountering due to "max-width:fit-content" which is applied on div.man.When using fit-content, the width of the element will be set to the minimum necessary to contain its content. This might cause the margin you've applied to the div not to be respected because the content is taking up the available space.
To resolve this, you can consider setting a specific width for the div.man element, rather than relying on fit-content. This will ensure that the margin is respected even when resizing the window.
Try to use this code ,I hope it works well


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    div.man {
      width: 500px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
      margin: 20px;
      display: flex;
    }
    div.man p {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    div.man img {
      max-width: 450px;
      height: auto;
    }
    @media (max-width: 655px) {
      div.man {
        flex-direction: column;
        width: auto; /* Reset width for smaller screens */
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px;">
  <div class="man">
<!--replace the img src whatever u want-->
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/young-bearded-man-with-striped-shirt_273609-5677.jpg">
    <p>Questo concept restaurant desidera donare ai propri membri un viaggio sensoriale e spirituale tramite le linee
  del design, l'attenta scelta dei suoni, l'accurata selezione delle essenze, un'altra riflessione della
  funzionalità e della comodità
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>




In your case, the image has given a max-width property. but width not restricted to maximum of 100% of parent div.
try to change the width of the image.then the problem will solve
